# order - viewCount is showing wrong results in "YouTube API v3"

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get videos of a particular channel (like :- Luis Fonsi) in `highest views order`. And I am passing `order parameter` to sort the response by `viewCount`

like :-

> order=viewCount

URL :-

> [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=[MY-API-KEY]&channelId=UCxoq-PAQeAdk_zyg8YS0JqA&part=snippet,id&order=viewCount&maxResults=20000](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=%5BMY-API-KEY%5D&channelId=UCxoq-PAQeAdk_zyg8YS0JqA&part=snippet,id&order=viewCount&maxResults=20000)

When I try to run it then It is not sorting as I expected. I was expecting first song would be `Despacito` But It got another one which definitely don't have the highest views.

As mentioned in `Youtube-API Documentation` in [search section](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters).
**viewCount – Resources are sorted from highest to lowest number of views.**

It is not working like this.

I have tried many times but it is still not working.

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Comment: Check the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) i seem to remember sort has been broken for a while.

Comment: YouTube Data API v3 is broken on some aspects, if I were you, I would just retrieve all videos from the given YouTube channel and then sort them.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison, That is really a good suggesstion

Comment: @BenjaminLoison, How can I make it show viewCount ? I mean , It is not showing viewCount

Comment: I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72393493/7123660) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube Data API v3 is broken on some aspects, if I were you, I would just retrieve all videos from the given YouTube channel and then sort them.

To do so:

1. Get the channel's `uploads` playlist id by using [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) with `part=contentDetails`.
2. Get the channel's videos by using [PlaylistItems:
   list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)
   with `playlistId=UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID` (replacing
   `UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID` with the one you just obtained).
3. Get each
   video's view count by using `part=statistics` with [Videos:
   list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list).